# How can I print Legal size PDF page on two Letter pages?

Tags: pdf, printing

1. I have standard Adobe PDF Reader.
2. I have a PDF of Legal size
3. I would like to print it on Letter page, so that what does not fit below automatically goes on to the second Letter page.

"Poster" printing does not do it.

In other words, I would like to print a (potentially) very long monolithic PDF on multiple Letter pages (similar to how a long web page would is printed).

Can that be achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that the best way possible you'll have to use a different PDF Reader. Foxit Reader is a free and very feature-rich PDF reader, download it from here: [www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader) (it is better to watch out while installing not to accept the trial for the premium version.)

In Foxit, you can choose when printing the **Tile Large Pages** option, and if you set the **Page Zoon** to **95%** it will print to letter pages in portrait.

See here, an 8.5x56 inch long PDF printing on 5 portrait letter papers:
[image]

---

In Adobe you can do it but it will print the letter pages in landscape.

You printing as Poster. It takes the Legal sized page and cuts it into two letter sized pages.

I had two legal and got four letters.

Settings were like this:
[image]

Or see this very long page gets divided into three:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. The problem there is that content gets rotated and is printed in landscape mode - you can see that it's 11 inches wide, which is the height of Letter. Is there a way to retain portrait orientation?

Comment: You are right. That isn't possible with Adobe AFAIK. I'll add now how to do that with Foxit Reader.